# facebook social plugin API: assign data when clicking button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your Website Title</title>
    <!-- You can use open graph tags to customize link previews.
    Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
    <meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
    <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
    <meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <!-- Your like button code -->
    <div class="fb-like" 
        data-href="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" 
        data-layout="standard" 
        data-action="like" 
        data-show-faces="true">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

In our case a page has a list of products and each product should have its own Like button.

```
  Product 1: Like Share
  Product 2: Like Share
  Product 3: Like Share
  Product 4: Like Share
  Product 5: Like Share
  Product 6: Like Share
```

How to achieve this? If a page has one product, we can use meta og:xxx.

When user clicks Like button for a product, is there a way to assign the meta properties dynamically? Thanks.

Comment: You give each products like button a unique URL. And then on that unique URL you add meta tags for that product.

Comment: The product image will be fetched from the unique product page(follow data-ref), not from the meta tags of current product list page? Thanks.